# Flutter 3.0 shows error : WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => widget.onReady.call());

Tags: flutter, dart, upgrade, flutter-3.0

After the upgrade project in flutter 3.0 it shows the following error.

```
    Syncing files to device iPhone 13 Pro Max...
../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/another_transformer_page_view-1.1.0/lib/src/another_transformer_page_view.dart:519:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
      WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(_onGetSize);
                     ^
../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/another_transformer_page_view-1.1.0/lib/src/another_transformer_page_view.dart:537:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
      WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(_onGetSize);
                     ^
../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_login-3.2.0/lib/src/widgets/animated_text.dart:57:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^
../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/awesome_select-5.2.0/lib/src/widget.dart:1547:58: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window);
                                                         ^
../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/awesome_select-5.2.0/lib/src/text_error.dart:99:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
```

it's bug from flutter? Can anyone report this to flutter. i don't know to report this to flutter team.

> ***This Warning bug is resolved.*** see my comment in correct answer I have written ( if you are a mac user goto finder -> press goto button by **swift+cmd+G**  -> past all 6 files I have mentioned or you find an error and replace **[root-name]** with **your root directory name.**

Comment: try to do flutter clean , flutter pub update and  cd ios and pod install and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'WidgetsBinding.instance' getter used to be a nullable type. In the new update it is changed to a Non-nullable. So, now old packages show this after the update because they used null aware operator there. It will be fixed in the new versions. For now you can just remove the null aware operator from the lines that show up in the logs and after rebuild there will be no more warnings.

Comment: Yes, it's just warning i have removed the null operator from each file where the error is showing.

Comment: for mac user press : Swift + window/CMD key + G ( open goto file dialog) and past this files path

Comment: 1) /Users/[root-name]/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_login-3.2.0/lib/src/widgets/animated_text.dart

Comment: 2) /Users/[root-name]/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/another_transformer_page_view-1.1.0/lib/src/another_transformer_page_view.dart

Comment: 3) /Users/[root-name]/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/awesome_select-5.2.0/lib/src/widget.dart

Comment: 4) /Users/[root-name]/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/awesome_select-5.2.0/lib/src/text_error.dart

Comment: 5) /Users/[root-Name]/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/awesome_select-5.2.0/lib/src/modal.dart

Comment: 6) /Users/[root-name]/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart

Answer (score 0):

it's bug from lib you used in your project, Don't worry. It will fix in next version dependency of lib

Or you can fork code from lib, fix it, and create a pull request to main

[example of this issue](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/732)

use

```
cached_network_image:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/XuannThucc/flutter_cached_network_image.git
      path: cached_network_image
      ref: ff72f00f142f13d889d7549e013af91cb0b523ab
```

instead of

```
cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
```

or wait for update `cached_network_image: ^3.2.1`

Comment: I make changes as per your suggestion but it's not working. Error is still same

Comment: i am already Using:  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1

Comment: these warnings are just warnings. Very annoying, but still compiling and running fine.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. Let me know if there is solution to remove this warning.